# Scrollbars not appearing in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns. The first column is a DataGridViewImageColumn type and shouldn't be re-sizable as per a requirement. So just for that column I have set Resizable = false.
Requirement also says that the last column should fill the DataGrid. Hence only for the last column I have set  AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill.

Now, whenever I am resizing the columns on the screen by expanding them, the scrollbars aren't appearing. Kindly help me find a workaround to fix the issue.

Please note - I have following properties already set in the code.

dgv.Columns["For All the columns I have Set"].Frozen = false

dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

dgv.AllowUserToResizeColumns = True;

dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;

Comment: You are using "Fill" attribute for ColumnMode property so every time you made changes in columns size it auto arrang other columns to get fit in datagridview and that's why scroll bar are not visible. Please change columnMode property.

Comment: @NayanKatkani I have done it on purpose for just the last column of the DataGridView as the requirement expects the last column to span fully till the top - right edge of the grid. I couldn't find a better solution to achieve it other than 'Fill' attribute.

Comment: In that case you can go with fixed column size for all columns rather then last column and on "Change Column Size" event change ColumnMode property so it will be condition based and only last column will get arranged.